# Product and sum principle question.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

here is the question I am trying to solve:

Maya is invited to a wedding. She gets all the items ( dresses, blouses, dress pants, shoes, necklaces and a scarf) she finds suitable to wear out of her closet.

a) Maya has two dress pants and four blouses. How many outfits does she have consisting of a blouse and a pair of pants?

My answer is 2.4.

b) She finds 3 suitable dresses. How many outfits does she have consisting of a pants outfit or a dress?

My answer is 3 as letter b) never spoke about pants and I am using the sum rule.

c) Maya finds five pairs of shoes, two of them with high heels not suitable for pants outfit. How many outfits does she have consisting of pants, a blouse, and shoes?

My answer is zero as letter c) did not speak about any blouse am I correct? is letter c) is related to the previous letters?( the question has many other letters that will have an answer of zero if each letter is treated independent of the previous letters).

Comment: It seems fairly clear that the information given in the different parts of the question is meant to be cumulative.

Comment: I suspect your answer to (a) is supposed to be $8$ and the answer to (b) is supposed to be $8+3=11$.

Comment: yeah it is 2 \times 4

Comment: @Henry it is 2 times 4 which is 8